# What does "even" mean here?

Tags: grammar

> Claude Lanzmann, who has realized, aesthetically, the experience of the death camps through the bearing of witness—and, in the process, has sought to define what might **even** constitute an image of the murder of European Jews at the hands of the Nazis [Source](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/movies/2014/01/hitchcock-and-the-holocaust.html)

What does this "even" mean here and what is its impact on the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: It's a very long noun phrase, not a sentence.  (In the link you've provided, it's part of a complete sentence.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "even" in this sense means that something is unexpected or extreme but is nevertheless true or possible. It is often used with a conditional word, like "might even" or "may even".

So for example you might say, "Jack is tall. He may EVEN be over six feet." Or, "We welcome all nationalities in our club. We even accept French people."

Comment: But in this context it doesn't make sense

Comment: The writer is saying that "the bearing of witness ... might even constitute an image of the murder". That is, we would not normally expect such testimony to be this kind of image, but in this case it is.

Comment: But the subject is not that but "Claude"

Comment: @birdman The subject of the verbgroup *might constitute* is *what*, not *Claude*.

Comment: oh yes. but what is not specified here. So this even doesn't make sense.

Comment: @birdman *What* here is the head of a free relative clause - understand it as *something which*

Comment: "What" here is the thing that might constitute an image. "What" (along with other interrogative words) is often used as a placeholder for an unknown. Like if I ask, "What is the name of your dog?", "what" is a placeholder for the unknown name. In this case he is linking this back to the "bearing of witness", but that connection is not so much indicated by the structure of the sentence as by the logical concept being built.